Economic elasticity from a continuous-time dynamical systems perspective
I note that in system dynamics (Forrester (1961) Industrial Dynamics; Sterman (2000) Business Dynamics), which is applying differential-equation models to the social sciences, the concept of elasticity as it is commonly used in Economics or Econometrics, is typically interpreted rather literally without taking the time dimension into account (cf. Kleemann et al. (2022) Elasticity formulations).
Typically, (constant) elasticity is defined using this identity (see 406845):
\begin{align}
\varepsilon = \frac{\frac{dy}{y}}{\frac{dx}{x}} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{x}{y}
\end{align}
But I find that the following interpretation is much more natural in continuous time dynamical systems:
\begin{align}
\varepsilon = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{x}{y} \frac{dt}{dt} = \frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}} \frac{x}{y}
\end{align}
Which then can be rearranged to reveal that the fractional rate of change of $y$ is a scaled version of that for $x$, where $\varepsilon$ is a "dynamic scaling factor" (it will be the coefficient of proportionality for constant $\epsilon$):
\begin{align}
\frac{\dot{y}}{y} = \varepsilon \frac{\dot{x}}{x} 
\end{align}
Unfortunately, I have difficulties finding sources for this interpretation and would greatly appreciate some pointers. Also, are there reasons for this interpretation to not be more widespread in continuous time systems modeling, e.g., using "momentum-related" equations may eventually introduce higher than first-order differential equations?
Disclaimer:
I am aware of a somewhat "sloppy" notation here, but it should suffice to sketch the basic ideas. Also, we are neglecting (for now) the conditionality arising from the need to prevent division by zero.

Since $\epsilon$ is not constant I wouldn't say rhat the fractional rate of change of y is proportional to that of x.
